# How can I make an Android feedback form submit as an email?

Tags: android

I'm making an Android app that is a basic user-input feedback form, and at the end, there is a submit button. First, I can't figure out how to make the button active, but I also want to format it so that the person's name that they gave is the subject to an email it would send me. I basically want the information they input to come to me as an email, and I'm confused how to implement this. Thanks!

Comment: I still cant find out how to correctly implement this with no errors...

Comment: What didn't work with @melvkim's solution?

Comment: @Ahmad perhaps it did, but I can't make it work in my code. I don't know if I'm not putting it in the right spot, or what, but I can't even get the onclick listener to well, listen. I'm also unsure if I'm to fill in certain things within his code? (My own variables, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a `Button` called `mBtnFeedback` in "FeedbackActivity.java", you can dynamically add the following to register the basic feedback functionality:

```
mBtnFeedback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              String to = textTo.getText().toString();
              String message = textMessage.getText().toString();
              String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();

              Intent mEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              mEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
              mEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
              mEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

              // prompts to choose email client
              mEmail.setType("message/rfc822");

              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mEmail, "Choose an email client to send your feedback!"));

            }
        });
```

For more information about `rfc822`, please refer to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) Wikipedia page.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without opening an external email client?

Comment: @coltsfan95 You have to create additional activities that handle additional tasks, including setting up protocol (e.g. smtp), port, password authentication, etc. Or, you can import [javamail-android](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) as class lib to your project and use its API.

Comment: ok, so if I do this, how much of what you provided is a placeholder? I'm getting many errors

Comment: @coltsfan95 Could you be more specific about your question? What "placeholder" are you referring to?

Comment: Like are certain aspects of this code just to hold the places until I fill in my own information? Also, I don't think I've correctly implemented the onclicklistener.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Take the form data

Step 2) Organize your form data

Step 3) Organize an intent and pass in the respective **extras** for your content (read the documentation on Intent.SEND_TO)

After this is all completed, you will achieve your result.

Comment: I've set it up so far so that the information can be input, but I'm confused as to how the Intent.SEND_TO works. Can I declare their input as a string, and then assign those strings to different components of the email?

Comment: **different** components of the intent's extras that are related to SEND_TO.

Answer (score 0):

I am an Android phone user seeking the help of Google/Android to overcome the menace of mobile phone spam messages (sms & mms) sent by telcos and third parties with permission of telcos. The current spam messages fltering function in Android can only block mobile numbers (not alphabet-type shortcodes) after the mobile numbers have been used to send spam messages.

It does not prevent third party spammers from registering new simcards nor telcos from sending spam messages using alphabet-type shortcodes.

I have an idea on how Android’s spam messages filtering function can be changed (new approach) that wil make it useless for third party spammers to register new simcards to send spam messages and prevent telcos from using alphabet-type shortcodes to send spam messages.

Please give me the email address of the right person in Google/Android so that I can explain my idea of improving Android’s spam messages filtering function or forward this email to that person and ask him/her to contact me.

Comment: @JamesAMohler Why did you edit this post? This is not an answer to the question and therefore should be deleted. By editing the post, you have kicked it out of the review queue - **[see here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15241284)**. Please flag the answer as not-an-answer so that it can be reviewed again. Thanks.